# Simplifying MySQL query - 2 queries into 1

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | entity | word  |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 | red   |
|  2 |      1 | green |
|  3 |      1 | blue  |
|  4 |      2 | car   |
|  5 |      2 | truck |
|  6 |      2 | train |
|  7 |      3 | water |
|  8 |      3 | milk  |
|  9 |      3 | soda  |
+----+--------+-------+
```

If I do a search for `blue` I would like to get `red`, `green` and `blue` as an answer. Right now I am using 2 queries. One to find the 'entity' number and one to find all the words with the same 'entity' number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Join is much faster than subquery

```
select distinct t2.word from Table t1 
INNER JOIN Table t2 on t2.entity=t1.entity
where t1.word="blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE entity IN
    (SELECT entity
     FROM TABLE_NAME
     WHERE word='blue');
```

Comment: Hi there! So... it's a bad practice to "just put the code" in an answer. Could you add a little more context? Usually a small explanation of what you did would be enough. Thanks!